# Getting error while talking to remote Oracle DB using Jenkins-CI

Tags: oracle, jenkins, devops

I am trying to connect to Oracle DB using Jenkins, I am trying to use the sqlplus-script-runner-plugin. Running into below issue

```
ERROR: ORACLE_HOME directory [/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1] does not exist!
```

[Sample Screenshot from Jenkins Job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYbjW.png)

I even try to add the Jenkins user to ointsall group on remote Oracle DB server. Can any one help me finding the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've to install Oracle XE to talk to remote DB servers, it solved my problem.